# Storing Results in n*m Matrix in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, multidimensional-array

I want to store the results into a matrix of 4*9. I have posted my code and i am using nested for loop.

I am having difficulties in how to store to results.

```
for d in range(4):
    for l in range(9):
         a=Swaps(n,d)
         k=Permute1(a,v,n)
         d = {x[-1]: x[:-1] for x in k}
         y= Permute2(a,v1,n)
         d1 = {x[-1]: x[:-1] for x in y}
         n=Bidirectional_Search(d,d1) #where n is a string
```

any help would be really appreciated

Comment: This link may help you: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_2darray.htm

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. could you please specify how can i store the string value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create an empty list outside of the loop.

```
matrix = []
    for d in range(4):
        row = []
        for l in range(9):
             a=Swaps(n,d)
             k=Permute1(a,v,n)
             d = {x[-1]: x[:-1] for x in k}
             y= Permute2(a,v1,n)
             d1 = {x[-1]: x[:-1] for x in y}
             n=Bidirectional_Search(d,d1) #where n is a string
             row.append(n)
        matrix.append(row)
```

There will be a list of lists after this operation.

```
matrix == [
    [element00, element01, ..., element08],
    [element10, element11, ..., element18],
    [element20, element21, ..., element28],
    [element30, element31, ..., element38],
]
```

You can access elememnts using following syntax:

```
matrix[0][1] # will return element01
```